# "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:" Error on cloud Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat7, servlet-3.0

I have deployed my web application on Tomcat server (i.e on cloud).

For two days it worked fine. Today I am getting this error.

How can I solve it?

> Error:-java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll
>   on a IA 32-bit platform

Comment: We need more infos.It's an empty tomcat? are you deploying something? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for response.(Tomcat is not empty.) I have deployed my web application on Tomcat server(i.e on cloud) before 2 days ago and every day I am restarting the tomcat server. The web application is working fine from last 2 days but today, I am getting above error, I don't know why above error occurred and how to solve it.